# SAS Infile statemnt delimiter

Tags: file-io, sas, delimiter

I have a data which looks like:
[image: Data]

Problem is, I am not understanding what delimiter is this which looks like tao function. I am using:

```
infile ecm dlm='09'X dsd truncover lrecl=4096 firstobs=1;
```

Any help is appreciated. Many thanks! :)

Comment: I don't see any tabs in that screen shot so it doesn't make sense to use tab as the delimiter in your INFILE statement. Looks like you have pipes as delimiters between the first three fields.  But perhaps the strange character is an internal delimiter within the third field.  Just ask SAS to show you what character that is.  Read in one line and try using the `list;` statement or use `put` with the `$HEX` format to see what character it is.

Comment: You possibly have multiple delimiters, tau and pipe. Can you confirm this? Do you have a record layout file that accompanies this? And is it possible this file is coming from a different language, or encoding that's causing the issue?

Comment: Ok..how can I solve for this? Or, how can I confirm this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use that character directly in the infile statement. For that simply copy the character and don't use the x to indicate hex literal.

```
infile ecm dlm='┌' dsd truncover lrecl=4096 firstobs=1;
```

That may fail when the encoding of the file is different from the encoding of your SAS session.

Comment: Can you give error message? Also can you cop portion of your file instead of picture